# Как создать счет через REST API ONLYOFFICE?

Tags: php, api, curl, crm, onlyoffice

В документации API OnlyOffice описаны методы работы с API. Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу создать при помощи API новый счет со стороннего PHP приложения.

В начале следует авторизоваться??

Comment: https://api.onlyoffice.com/portals/section/crm/invoices